# Interprete PointCloud2 messages of Kinect

Tags: kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

how do I get the distance values out of the PointCloud2 message produced by a Kinect sensor efficiently? At the moment I use a loop iterating all points and writing the z-value to a file.

Thanks for your help

Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30714/interprete-pointcloud2-messages-of-kinect/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) tutorials; this will get you a PCL point cloud, rather than a ROS PointCloud2; the PCL version comes with all kinds of useful gadgetry.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1